# Loop in Excel to print numbers in rows. repetitive number loop in Excel

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

How to make a loop in Excel VBA that will print a number for certain Rows and then move to another number for other Rows. This is what I want my loop to do:

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
```

I am unable to get the loop right.[This is the OutPut that I want to Automate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ZEp.png)

---

Comment: It isn't clear what the question actually is or where you are stuck. It would help if you showed the code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
Sub FillNumbers(start As Range, n As Long, k As Long)
    Dim block As Range, i As Long
    For i = 1 To n
        Set block = Range(start.Offset(k * (i - 1)), start.Offset(k * i - 1))
        block.Value = i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Then, for example, the sub call

```
FillNumbers Range("A1"),5,12
```

will fill the range `A1:A60` with the numbers 1-5 in blocks of size 12.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub whatever()
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 5
            Cells(k, 1) = i
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]